# Из чего состоит объектный файл с++?

Tags: c++, компилятор

Из чего состоит объектный файл с++? И как в нем разобраться?

Comment: У разных компиляторов - совершенно по-разному. Зачем в нем разбираться - тоже не особо ясно

Comment: Куча кода на низкоуровневом языке, в котором вызовы функций и методов заменены на их сигнатуры в специальном виде. Дальше, во время линковки, вместо этих сигнатур поставляются нужные адреса.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко это я как раз понимаю. 
тыньк https://habr.com/ru/post/150327/

Comment: @Ildar Все что нашел реально интересного по ссылке на ответ Дмитрию. 
Этого оказалось крайне мало. Структуру объектного файла я так и не понял.

Comment: @VTT это просто любопытство. Желание разобраться с компилятором. Ничего больше. Я  понимаю как все работает на всех  этапах компиляции, кроме линковщика.

Comment: [objdump t.o -a -f -x](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) и [man 5 elf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/elf) (это так называется формат объектного файла)

Comment: @WierdGreenCat, раз все понимаете кроме линкера, значит пора его написать. В процессе и разберетесь.